# Coordinates of cropped ROI

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I have an image and some ROIs (in form of seperate files) cropped from it. I want to find the coordinates of corner points of these ROI in the original image. 
Is there a simple way to do this besides checking for all pixel values in the original image ?

Example - 
Entire Image
[image: Entire Image]

Cropped ROI

[image: Cropped ROI]

I need to find the coordinates of the car in the original image.

Comment: Give your example.

Comment: what do you mean? you have separate images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cropped image isn't rotated or scaled then you can do template matching. Your ROI image will be your template. [Check this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#code), This will draw a rectangle over your original image from where you can get the coordinates.

Comment: You can still do template matching when the crops aren't exact. With template matching you can find the best match, it doesn't have to be exactly equal.

Comment: Though template matching gives minmaxloc, it is not rotation and scale invariant. That's why I wrote it as exactly cropped. I have changed it now. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

If the crops are exact (i.e. no changes from the original pixels were introduced after cropping, for example as a result of JPG compression when saving), then you could use integral images to speed up the search.

Compute the sum of the pixel values of the cropped images, then the integral image of the original ones, then use the integral image to search for a window of equal size of the crop that has equal sum. This algorithm is, of course, linear time in the size of the original image.

Note that the sum is a "weak" signature, and you may find multiple matches, but you can then verify these candidate matches directly at the pixel level.

Comment: Never seen an integral image used in this sense, I love the idea. However looping through numpy arrays is slow (whereas the template matching in OpenCV is extremely snappy), so I don't think the search in the integral image would be fast as implemented in standard Python.